# PHP script that sends an email listing file changes that have happened in a directory/subdirectories

Tags: php, ftp, cron

I have a directory with a number of subdirectories that users add files to via FTP. I'm trying to develop a php script (which I will run as a cron job) that will check the directory and its subdirectories for any changes in the files, file sizes or dates modified. I've searched long and hard and have so far only found one script that works, which I've tried to modify - original located [here](http://forums.jumba.com.au/showthread.php?9969-FTP-Notification-For-New-Files&p=111273&viewfull=1#post111273)  - however it only seems to send the first email notification showing me what is listed in the directories. It also creates a text file of the directory and subdirectory contents, but when the script runs a second time it seems to fall over, and I get an email with no contents.

Anyone out there know a simple way of doing this in php? The script I found is pretty complex and I've tried for hours to debug it with no success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How big are the files that you're tracking?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
$log = '/path/to/your/log.js';
$path = '/path/to/your/dir/with/files/';
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
$result = array();

foreach ($files as $file)
{
    if (is_file($file = strval($file)) === true)
    {
        $result[$file] = sprintf('%u|%u', filesize($file), filemtime($file));
    }
}

if (is_file($log) !== true)
{
    file_put_contents($log, json_encode($result), LOCK_EX);
}

// are there any differences?
if (count($diff = array_diff($result, json_decode(file_get_contents($log), true))) > 0)
{
    // send email with mail(), SwiftMailer, PHPMailer, ...
    $email = 'The following files have changed:' . "\n" . implode("\n", array_keys($diff));

    // update the log file with the new file info
    file_put_contents($log, json_encode($result), LOCK_EX);
}
```

I am assuming you know how to send an e-mail. Also, please keep in mind that the `$log` file should be kept outside the `$path` you want to monitor, for obvious reasons of course.

<s>After reading your question a second time, I noticed that you mentioned you want to check if the *files* change, I'm only doing this check with the size and date of modification, if you really want to check if the file contents are different I suggest you use a hash of the file, so this:</s>

```
$result[$file] = sprintf('%u|%u', filesize($file), filemtime($file));
```

Becomes this:

```
$result[$file] = sprintf('%u|%u|%s', filesize($file), filemtime($file), md5_file($file));
// or
$result[$file] = sprintf('%u|%u|%s', filesize($file), filemtime($file), sha1_file($file));
```

But bare in mind that this will be much more expensive since the hash functions have to open and read all the contents of your 1-5 MB CSV files.

Comment: Hi Alix, thanks, I meant if the file names change rather than the contents of the file so the first set of code should be fine. I'll give it a go! I was toying around just now with a script that put the file names, sizes and dates modified into a mysql table and then queried the table against the directory contents each time the script was run - but your method seems much cleaner!

Comment: @estebannn: You can make it work with MySQL too, but I honestly don't see the need for that in your particular scenario and yes, it will work with sub(-sub-...)directories as well since I used the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` class.

Comment: @estebannn: I am sorry but my code had two bugs, I've been drinking and I guess my analytical skills aren't at the level they should be to make my code bug-free. They are fixed now however. =)

Answer (score 0):

I like sfFinder so much that I wrote my own adaption:

http://www.symfony-project.org/cookbook/1_0/en/finder

https://github.com/homer6/altumo/blob/master/source/php/Utils/Finder.php

Simple to use, works well.

However, for your use, depending on the size of the files, I'd put everything in a git repository. It's easy to track then.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for the response! I think what I need may be simpler than this, however. The files in question are 1-5Mb csv files. I basically just need to check at any given time if the user(s) have modified the file in the directory since the last time I checked, and then have the script send me an email listing the files that have changed. Again, thank you for such a quick response, it is appreciated!

Comment: @Alix: Don't put other answers down when you post answers yourself. It's not classy. sfFinder will help, but as you can see, I also proposed using git for finding file deltas.

Comment: @Homer6: What makes you so sure that I down voted you?! False accusation is not classy either... As for your answer, none of the options you recommended truly answer the OP question and thus don't expect to receive praise from it.

Comment: @Alix: I didn't say you voted me down. I said you downed my answer, as in criticized. Which you did; thus, it's not a false accusation. It's what really happened.  :-) Nevertheless, you did contribute an answer, so kudos to you on that front.

Comment: @Homer6: Oh! Well, I wasn't trying to be rude, just pointing out a fact. If the OP isn't able to understand sfFinder code he might ending up struggling with it for a couple of hours before he realizes what it does. Sorry if I came a bit too harsh. =)